# Java Connection pool exhausted error

Tags: java, connection, pool

I know normally if the error happened, i mean `org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool exhausted`, which means the conenction is overloaded. but in this case, I pretty sure there's no connection to my local mysql server(I used 'show processlist' command).

is there any other place can cause this error?

bellow is my code:

```
try {
    // Obtain a connection
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(jndiSrc);
    _log.info("==============" + jndiSrc + " is bound to " + ds + "=====================");
    return ds.getConnection(); 
}
```

Comment: Are you closing the connections you retrieve from the connection source?

Comment: Also, what is the pool size you have set in the `DataSource`?